# Efficient algorithm for strings - regex matching

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm, data-structures

Problem statement:

> Given two list A of strings and B of regex's(they are string too).
>   For every regex in list B, find all the matching strings in list A.
>   Length of list A <= 10^6 (N)
>   Length of string B <= 100 (M)
>   Length of strings, regex <= 30 (K)
>   Assume regex matching and string comparisons take O(K) time and regex can contain any python regex supported operations.

My algorithm:

```
for regex in B:
    for s in A:
        if regex.match(s):
            mapping[regex].add(s)
```

This takes `O(N*M*K)` time.
Is there any way to make it more time efficient even compromising space (using any data structure)?

Answer (score 0):

This is about as fast as it can go, in terms of time complexity.

Every regex *has* to be matched with every string at least once. Otherwise, you won't be able to get the information of "match" or "no match".

In terms of absolute time, you can use a [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to avoid the slow Python loops:

```
mapping = {regex: filter(re.compile(regex).match, A) for regex in B}
```